# EXCEL #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, function, excel-2007

I am using this function =IF(H9-D9-I9-J9=0,"",H9-D9-I9-J9) however instead of displaying nothing it displays #VALUE! when the first statement is true. It works if the first statement is false.

Comment: And what are the actual contents of the cells used in that formula? That might be handy to know, don't ya think :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the investigation. Try to look if the value of H9,D9,I9 and J9 is a NUMBER. Maybe there is STRING value in H9,D9,I9 and J9 that cause **#VALUE!**.

Comment: What do you mean by this? H9 has this function =IF(F9+G9=0,"",(F9+G9)) D9 has this function =IF(B7="","",VLOOKUP(B7,Products!$A$5:$K$29,11,FALSE)) as for I9 and J9 their values are just input and they are numbers

Comment: Try =H9-D9-I9-J9 in a cell, and see if the result is a number. If not, comparing it to zero may cause problems.

Comment: The function of H9 has a tendency to have a string value which is "". Try to change "" into 0.'=IF(F9+G9=0,0,(F9+G9))' to avoid **#VALUE!**

Comment: Also the function of D9...Change it to =IF(B7="",0,VLOOKUP(B7,Products!$A$5:$K$29,11,FALSE))..

Comment: This still doesn't fix it, I'll just apply the function to the cell manually once each other cell has values for the function because these #VALUE error comes up a lot and its getting annoying. I'd think it be easier to manually apply the function once I have data in the cells Thanks to everyone though!

Comment: I think your just testing. OK..Good luck.

Comment: well you shouldn't accept this answer (the same as my comment elsewhere) given it wasn't a solution. Can you post a sample workbook somewhere for us to look at?